# How to add lines to a textarea which contains mailto links in java?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, textarea, mailto

I need to add lines to the textarea in swing which contains the mailto links and clicking on it should open email application.

How can I do it?

Comment: You should try JTextPane instead of JTextArea.

Comment: I append text to textArea, could you please give a example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I have suggested in my comment *You should try JTextPane instead of JTextArea*.

In order to make hyper link work you need to do following things:

- make textPane editable = false.
- add a HyperlinkListener to it so that you can  monitor link activate event.

A quick demo is as follows:

```
    final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    textPane.setEditable(false);
    textPane.setContentType("text/html");
    textPane.setText("File not found please contact:<a href='mailto:michael@uml.com'>e-mail to</a> or call 9639");
    textPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
        @Override
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                System.out.println(e.getURL());
                // write your logic here to process mailTo link.
            }
        }
    });
```

Example of opening mail client through java:

```
try {
    Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new URI(e.getURL() + ""));
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I get exception: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/awt/Desktop`

Comment: this is my java version: `C:\Users\ash>java version
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7.0_01', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.`